# Project only works when I include npm-shrinkwrap.json - Any downsides to continuing this way?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I spent about 12 hours getting my application working again after days and days of not building. I could only do so with `npm shrinkwrap`

Are there any significant downsides to this? I'd also be open to using `yarn` if there is some way that could possibly assist with this issue.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You're not very clear. Why do you **have** to use `npm shrinkwrap`? what happens if you don't?

Comment: Everything builds fine but it doesn't actually run. I get problems with `react-router` that I have not been able to resolve in any other way. The specifics are way beyond the scope of the question since I have already tried and failed with so many resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well there aren't really downsides to shrinkwrapping your package. I believe it's the preferred way to ship your package. That way you won't have issues with dependencies accidentally being upgraded and possibly messing up your package.

As to the differences between `yarn` and `npm`, it seems that yarn is currently the new hot stuff, but for basic usage `npm shrinkwrap` using npm >= 3 will do the job.

**Side Note**

Even though it's not a part of the question I would still suggest you re-check the reason your app doesn't work without shrinkwrap. It smells not so good.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Indeed it is not good to be needing shrinkwrap. Fortunately yarn has a new pre-release feature as of a week ago which really saved the day. `yarn import` built me a `yarn.lock` from the working `node_modules` folder, and it creates reproducible, working results.

Answer (score 0):

Shrinkwrap it looks like would be a nightmare to deal with long term. I came across a feature of `Yarn`, just added, that creates a `yarn.lock` file from your `node_modules` folder (as opposed to from a `package.json`)

Using `yarn import` I was able to create a `yarn.lock` which can be used to reliably install the application's dependencies.